# Gmail API credentialing?

Tags: c#, email, gmail-api

I set up the Gmail API credentialing process as follows:

```
string clientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret;
string clientId = Settings.ClientId;
Task<UserCredential> tCredential;
ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets {ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret};
tCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    clientSecrets,
    Scopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None);
UserCredential credential;
try
{
    credential = tCredential.Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
_service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Draft Sender", //applicationName,
});
```

I didn't set the credential to save in any kind of file.  However, when I run the code, I only get prompted to allow access to the email account once.  After the initial authorization, subsequent runs do not generate a prompt to authorize.  This was actually a good thing until I tried to change the email address I was accessing.

The way it works is I have two email addresses: a personal email address and a test email address.  I had the program working so that it accessed the content of my personal email address.  Then, I needed to develop code that deleted the messages, so I decided to switch to a test email address.

In order to access the email addresses using the Gmail API, you have to enable the API and generate a 'client id' and 'client secret' in the Google developer's console for each email address you want to access. I had generated both values for both the personal email and the test email.

Next, I updated the client id and client secret in the code so that my test email was targeted rather than my personal email.

When I updated the clientId and clientSecret to the new email address, I initially got an authorization prompt, but the authorization prompt was asking for access to the old email account.  I went ahead and authorized just to see what would happen.  Now, even with the changed clientId and secret, the program accesses the original email address.  I have even tried changing the secret for the original email address, but the program still has access.

I have to believe there is some kind of file that is storing the credentials, because how else could the program access the email inbox??  How do I find this file or get this code to access a different email inbox? Do I need to manually create a file in order to bypass whatever is automatically being done?

Comment: Are you trying to change email address of the user who created the project? please explain clearly what do you mean by updating "clientId and clientSecret to the new email address"?  Also, did you try deleting cookies while updating to new email?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to work around the problem without actually fixing it.  By refreshing the secret from the Gmail API console for all email addresses involved, I forced the authentication to expire.

Then, when I went in to reauthorize the program (when I ran it in Visual Studio, and IE came up with the authorization prompt), I made sure to change the gmail account (listed in the upper right) to the email account I wanted to authorize.

This worked; the fact that it worked and didn't work the first time suggests to me that there are some authentication issues...but I don't know what they are and speculation is inherently, well, speculative since I would have to know exactly what I did.

If there is someone who understands what is going on, I would really like to know, because I am still having problems changing the state of my authenticator (the scope) after granting access to an account (in other words: once I grant access, it seems that the access is locked in at that level, and no amount of changing options from the code seems to do anything).