# GMail API - authorising a second email account

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api

I am developing an app using VB.Net for accessing my GMail accounts. I was able to follow the steps given at .Net [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) and was able to able access one of my accounts. So whenever I run my app, it accesses my first gmail account automatically, which is fine. Now I would like to access my other gmail account using the same app. How to change the gmail account that is automatically accessed by my desktop app?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460584/gmail-api-credentialing), but I am not able to understand the answer provided there

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Before using your app, you need to log out of the default gmail account (i.e., first gmail account in your case). So I think you need to log out from that first gmail account, then log in with the second gmail account and try to sign in from your app. Hope this helps!

Comment: No it doesn't help. Even when I am logged on to my second gmail account, my app accesses the first gmail account only

Comment: have you logged out from your first gmail account meanwhile? Infact second gmail account is the only one which is logged in when you are trying?

Comment: Yes, I tried 
* after logging in into my second account (no other logins)
* logged out of all gmail accounts
Still I am not able change my app to use the second gmail account

Comment: Try one more time by clearing all the history of your browser and app.

Comment: Even that did not help. The [.Net Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) says **Authorization information is stored on the file system, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization**. Where exactly it is stored?
Thanks for your  patience

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out where the authorization information is stored. It is stored in  **Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData** folder. A folder named **Google.Apis.Auth** is created under this folder and a new file with the authorization information is created under it *(in my case it is C:\Users\myWindowsUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth)*. I deleted the file which was there, which had the token for my first gmail ID. When I ran my app again, it asked for user login and consent once again, at which point I provided details of my second gmail account. This pearl is available [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications)